# How to show color on box after clicking color name

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display the colour named on a button in the output div tag after clicking the button.

Here is my javascript code so far and also my HTML and css code.
I tried to take the value, but it's not working.
I don't know how to capture this value.
I wish to create one event handler and assign it to all 3 buttons.
The code should assign the event handler through the CLASS attribute, but use the ID attribute to distinguish which button was clicked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".colorbutton").on("click", function() {
    var colorid = $(this).attr("id");

    $("#output").stop(true, true).hide().html(color).stop(true, true).show("fade", 1500);
  }); // end event handler
}); // ends document.ready
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://newton.ncc.edu/gansonj/ite154/img/crayons.jpg");
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: right;
  color: #008B8B;
}

#pagewrap {
  border: 8px #800000 solid;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 600px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  margin: 40px auto 0px auto;
}

#title {
  font-size: 2.2em;
  border-bottom: 7px #008B8B double;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  color: #008B8B;
  text-align: center;
}

#formtext {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.29em;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#usergrade {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px 20px 10px 20px;
}

.colorbutton {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
  border: 3px solid #CCCC99;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 150px;
}

.colorbutton:hover {
  background: #CCCCCC;
  color: yellow;
  border: 3px solid #003366;
}

#output {
  font-size: 5em;
  padding-top: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px auto 30px auto;
  border: 5px black double;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="pagewrap">

    <div id="title">Crayon Color Factory</div>

    <div id="formwrap" style="margin-top: 30px;">

      <input type="button" class="colorbutton" id="red" style="background-color:red;" value="RED Color">
      <input type="button" class="colorbutton" id="blue" style="background-color:blue;" value="BLUE Color">
      <input type="button" class="colorbutton" id="green" style="background-color:green;" value="GREEN Color">

      <div id="output">Change Me!!!!!</div>

    </div>
    <!-- ends div#formwrap -->

  </div>
  <!-- ends div#pagewrap -->

</body>

</html>
```

smaple picture here: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCtAx.png)

Comment: You assigned the variable `colorid` but then show `color`. Change them to the same variable and it will work. Didn't you see the error message in the console?

Comment: its not cheating ,its a pracrice at home for exam and I am just want suggestion..Hope you understand..Thanks

Comment: @JK. THey're not asking us to do it for them. They wrote the code, they're having trouble, and they're looking for help.

Comment: @Barmar Exactly

Comment: I crack it.. Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to display the colour name in the box, you need to pass the string you assigned to the html function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".colorbutton").on("click", function() {
    var colorid = $(this).attr("id");

    $("#output").css("backgroundColor", colorid);
  }); // end event handler
}); // ends document.ready
```

This will change the background colour of the output box.

Comment: thanks but I want show the color not the color name

Comment: Then you need to set the style of the element, e.g. `$("output").css("backgroundColor", colorid)`

Comment: What Barmar said.
The background colour of the output box will now match the name on the button clicked, @RaselIslam.

Comment: @sanepete
I got that part but i want show color in the box when I click color name.Lets say, I clicked on red button , and then the box will appear in color red not the text red.

Comment: I edited my code to do just that @RaselIslam.

Comment: thank you @sanepete . I already solved it

Answer (score 0):

The color variable is not defined.

```
$("#output").stop(true,true).hide().html( color ).stop(true,true).show( "fade", 1500 );
```

You need to use the colorid variable instead.
here is the code if you want to change the color and  the string inside the box.

```
document.getElementById("output").style.color = colorid; 
$("#output").stop(true,true).hide().html( colorid ).stop(true,true).show( "fade", 1500 );
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is pass your *button id's* and make *eventlistener*. So every time you click the button, the background color of your div is change depend on the value.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const red = document.getElementById('red');
    const blue = document.getElementById('blue');
    const green = document.getElementById('green');
    const output = document.getElementById('output');

    red.addEventListener('click', function onClick(event) {
        output.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    });
    blue.addEventListener('click', function onClick(event) {
        output.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    });
    green.addEventListener('click', function onClick(event) {
        output.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://newton.ncc.edu/gansonj/ite154/img/crayons.jpg");
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: right;
  color: #008B8B;
}

#pagewrap {
  border: 8px #800000 solid;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 600px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  margin: 40px auto 0px auto;
}

#title {
  font-size: 2.2em;
  border-bottom: 7px #008B8B double;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  color: #008B8B;
  text-align: center;
}

#formtext {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.29em;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#usergrade {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px 20px 10px 20px;
}

.colorbutton {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
  border: 3px solid #CCCC99;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 150px;
}

.colorbutton:hover {
  background: #CCCCCC;
  color: yellow;
  border: 3px solid #003366;
}

#output {
  font-size: 5em;
  padding-top: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px auto 30px auto;
  border: 5px black double;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<div id="pagewrap">
    <div id="title">Crayon Color Factory</div>
    <div id="formwrap" style="margin-top: 30px;">
        <input type="button" class="colorbutton" id="red" style="background-color:red;" value="RED Color">
        <input type="button" class="colorbutton" id="blue" style="background-color:blue;" value="BLUE Color">
        <input type="button" class="colorbutton" id="green" style="background-color:green;" value="GREEN Color">
        <div id="output">Change Me!!!!!</div>
    </div>
    <!-- ends div#formwrap -->
</div>
<!-- ends div#pagewrap -->
```